# List repetition (xx) without evaluation?

Tags: raku

The list repetition operator ([`xx`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/xx)) evaluates the list every time it is repeated. For example,

```
my @input = get() xx 5;
```

will evaluate to the first 5 lines of STDIN. Is there any way I can repeat just the *value* of the element 5 times, rather than evaluating it each time? Currently, I've been assigning it to a variable, then repeating it, but it seems a bit cumbersome that way.

```
my $firstLine = get();
my @firstlineRepeated = $firstLine xx 5;
```

Is there a prefix or something that lets me do it in one statement?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `given` to contextualize it into `$_` is one fairly neat way:

```
my @input = ($_ xx 5 given get());
say @input;
```

That, when I type `hello`, gives:

```
[hello hello hello hello hello]
```

Since `given` simply contextualizes, rather than doing any kind of definedness or truth test, it's a bit safer as a general pattern than `andthen`.

Comment: I had a thought like `@lines = ( state $ //= get() ) xx 5` but this is much nicer.

Comment: Nice. And, unlike [in the case of using `andthen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765739/list-repetition-xx-without-evaluation#comment90492975_51766735), the parens are optional because, while `given` also acts as a conjunction here, cleaving its LHS and RHS into a statement or expression on its left and an expression on its right, that works out to make sense (in two very different ways, but with the exact same end result) regardless of whether the parens are used or not.

Answer (score 7):

You could try use the [`andthen`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#infix_andthen) operator:

```
my @input = (get() andthen $_ xx 5);
```

From the documentation:

> The `andthen` operator returns Empty upon encountering the first
>   undefined argument, otherwise the last argument. Last argument is
>   returned as-is, without being checked for definedness at all.
>   Short-circuits. The result of the left side is bound to `$_` for the
>   right side, or passed as arguments if the right side is a Callable,
>   whose count must be 0 or 1.

Comment: I could swear I'd seen some idiom for this but I've not used it. So I searched high and low and didn't find it. Then thought about it, rejected several ugly options, and settled on the exact same line as you, character for character, went to publish it andthen... it was already published. :)

Comment: Hypothetically, what if the value was Nil? Wouldn't it shortcircuit?

Comment: NB. The conjunctions `and`, `or`, `andthen`, and `orelse` have very low precedence. They cleave the *one* outer statement/expression they're in the middle of into *two* statements/expressions. So if you want to use them in the middle of a single statement *without* cleaving it into two you *must* use parens to mark their containing expression. Hence, in this answer, the parens on the RHS of the `my @input = ...` are essential otherwise `@input` will end up with just one element and you'll get a `Useless use of $_ in sink context` warning. In other scenarios you won't even get the warning.

Comment: @JoKing Yes, it would shortcircuit. You could write `my @input = (get() // 'default' andthen $_ xx 5);`.

Answer (score 2):

Using phrase [`ENTER`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/phasers#ENTER) works too

```
my @input = ENTER { get() } xx 5;
```

Comment: It "works" in the sense of producing the right result for that precise code, but introduces `ENTER` semantics. In the code `say 42; ENTER { say 99 }`, the `99` would be said before the `42`.

Comment: @raiph You are right. `ENTER` is problematic. Maybe `my @input = do { ENTER { get() }  xx 5 }` fix this.